# Do I need to send an update to iOS app if I create Push Notification certificates afresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I had an app hosted in my organization's internal app store. The app has Push Notifications feature.

The distribution certificate (In-House type) using which the app was launched to internal store expires in Feb 2017.

However, the push notification certificates for the app got expired on August 15th, 2016 but we forgot to notice and came to know about this only yesterday. The users are not receiving any notifications post August 15th.

I have created new push notification certificates at the Member Center, .p12 of which I have shared with the application server team.

My questions are -

1. Do I need to regenerate the In-House Distribution certificate for the app at Member Center now?
2. If the answer to question 1 is Yes, do I need to send out an update to the app for the users to start receiving the push notifications again?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make a update for **App**. If certificate is expired, just generate the new certificate for development and production. Upload those certificates **p12** to your server.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a new certificate and replace the old one.

When your existing APNS certificate expired, if your server still uses it - existing iOS applications will not be able to receive any notifications from your server. But as soon as you regenerate certificate and update your server to use it - everything will be normal again without any changes to already installed apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to regenerate the certificate from member center and you need to update your server with new .pem/.p12 file used for sending push notifications

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate `.pem` file by using your `.p12` follow this - [Generate .pem file Used to setup Apple PUSH Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification)

Once you have `.pem` update your server with new `.pem` that's all. Now you should get notification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

1) Create new push certificate and .p12 file. Replace new .p12 file with the old one at the server.

2) You don't need to send update of your app.

Hope this helps!