# APNS certificate should be revoked before expiration or create after expiration

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My APNS certificates is about to expire in few days, the app is live on App Store.
Should I revoke it before its get expire or create after expiration ?

Would it make any impact if I revoked it before its got expired?

How much day we have to generate the certificate again after expiration.

Note: I have already renewed the developer program.

Thanks, in advance for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)

Comment: Push notifications certificate expire after one year..

Comment: agreed and i have renewed the account but what is the correct time to revoke or generate the certificate?

Comment: Please share your answer. If you get any   information

Answer (score 0):

> what is the correct time to revoke or generate the certificate?

For example :

if you crate now then your certificated saying this certificated valid this time next year so you want to renew every year .

**So you Should  revoke it before it's get expire .**