# ios push notification renewal

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

My push notification **certificate** expires in 10 days and I want to upload new one before it expires how should I do that. there is only **revoke** and **download**. So should I revoke it and then upload new generated certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)

Comment: They not explaining how to renew it..

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer: "The push certificate cannot be renewed. You have to create a new one."

Comment: yes but how to do that I mean I know how to generate it but do I need to revoke it and then change it?

Comment: Don't touch your old one yet. Generate a new one, and then update your push server with the new p12. Once you've verified your server is sending pushes with the new p12 you are safe to ditch the old one

Comment: @kosas, create a new one, don't touch anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Connect to your Apple Developer account
2. Go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
3. In the "Identifiers" section, go to "**App IDs**"
4. Select your app
5. Click on "Edit"
6. For each of your push certificates, in the section "Create an additional certificate to use for this App ID.", click on "Crete certificate..."
7. Do the usual procedure to generate the certificate request(s), upload, download the certificate(s).
8. Install it/them on your server or push gateway
9. Once you are using the new certificate(s), you can revoke the old one if you want to, but it will expire automatically anyway.

The trick is to get to the certificate through the App IDs rather than through the cert itself.

Alternative: go to the Certificates section, and click on the "+" button to create a new one, then follow the steps.