# Does Enabling CloudKit in Your App affects current app in Appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, cloudkit, provisioning-profile

I need to enable iCloud feature in my current app which has an existing version in AppStore.

What I can see from enabling the iCloud,
[image]

Is making my existing provisioning Invalid,
[image]

The **Invalid** is making me worried,
Will it effect my existing app in AppStore.

**Note***
I have tried the above in demo project.

Comment: No it does not affect live app

Comment: @MuseerAnsari: Thank you, May I know why the existing profiles are getting invalid, Is there any official documentation where this(invalid not affecting the official app) is addressed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working

Comment: @MuseerAnsari: Thank you. You could have also answered in Answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short No, it won't affect any of your existing apps on the App Store.

Modifying/Deleting any App-ID, Provisioning Profile or Certificate has no effect what so ever once you have submitted the App.

However, you will have to use the new configuration for your next release.

Comment: Thank you, also just to know wether it will have any effects on push notification in live since its associated with the app id (capabilities) ?

Comment: No, it will not affect that as well.