# How to send push notifications from AWS SNS using a Push Notification Key (p8 file)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

When faced with the task of renewing my soon to expire push certificate I stubled on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525082/1175081) of using a push notifications auth key which never expires.

Now I couldn't find a way to get it to work with AWS SNS, nor could I find any information on using p8 files with that service. Is it even possible?

Comment: did you finnd out

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SNS [now supports token-based authentication using .p8 key file](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-token-authentication-api-mobile-notifications/). You can also choose to use certificate-based authentication if you prefer.

You can learn more at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-apple-authentication-methods.html