# iOS - What to do after Pushnotification almost expired?

Tags: ios, swift

Please check if i'm correct ?

1) If push notification still not expired , just revoking and no need to mess with distribution nor development stuffs.

2) After revoked , Need to create new distribution / development and open Xcode , download the new distribution / development and re-deploy.

3) If push notification revoked what would happen to current users who has installed the App before revoke ?

Comment: Currently my distribution and development both brand new , the problem is push notification provisioning will expire in 3 days . I'm confused do i need to create newer distribution / dev certs if i hit those "Revoke" button for pushNotification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push certificates doesn't included in the build or final binary. If your certificates are expired then you need to create a new one and you can create `.p12` or `.pem` file and replace it with the older one in your server(which is sending notifications). There is no need to upload an update for the application with new certificate. In the future when you make any changes in the app and upload a new version at that time you will need to use newer certificates if you're signing manually.